# Consulta que no me muestra algunos campos en una tabla de página php

Tags: php, mysql, html5

tengo una página hecha en PHP que al entrar hace una consulta para mostrar datos en una tabla:

```
SELECT T3.nrologins, T1.idusuario, T1.razonsocial, T2.provincia, T2.pais, T1.servicios 
FROM usuarios_inst as T1 
INNER JOIN usuarios_base AS T2 ON T1.idusuario = T2.idusuario 
INNER JOIN usuarios AS T3 ON T1.idusuario = T3.id 
WHERE T1.visible = 1 AND T3.id_tipo <> 1 
ORDER BY T3.nrologins DESC
```

El tema es que si hago la consulta en mysql me devuelve registros tal como los pido, pero cuando la consulta la coloco en el código de la página, me muestra solo algunos datos de la consulta: me recupera la razon social, los servicios (que estan en la T1) pero todos los demás no los muestra...

```
$conexion = new Conexion();
$stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT T3.nrologins, T1.idusuario, T1.razonsocial, T2.provincia, T2.pais, T1.servicios FROM usuarios_inst as T1 INNER JOIN usuarios_base AS T2 ON T1.idusuario = T2.idusuario INNER JOIN usuarios AS T3 ON T1.idusuario = T3.id where T1.visible = 1 AND T3.id_tipo <> 1 ORDER BY T3.nrologins DESC");
$resultado = $stmt->execute();

//Creamos array con los datos
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

así armo la tabla:

```
<table id="tabla" class="ui celled stackable table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th hidden>nrologins</th>
                        <th hidden>Id</th>
                        <th>Instalador</th>
                        <th>Rubros</th>
                        <th>Provincia</th>
                        <th>País</th>
                        <th>Ver</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <?php
                if ($arrDatos) {
                    foreach ($arrDatos as $row) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td hidden>
                                <?php echo $row['nrologins']; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td hidden>
                                <?php echo $row['idusuario']; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['razonsocial']; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php
                                    //Traigo el array de los servicios
                                    $contador = 0;
                                    $servicios = $row['servicios'];
                                    $valores = json_decode ($servicios, true);
                                    $conexion = new Conexion();
                                    $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT id, detalle FROM instalador_servicios WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY detalle");
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                        if (in_array($row['id'], $valores)) {
                                            $contador = $contador + 1;
                                            if ($contador == 1) {
                                                echo utf8_encode($row['detalle']);
                                            } else {
                                                echo " / " . utf8_encode($row['detalle']);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['provincia']; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php
                                    $pais = $row['pais'];
                                    $conexion = new Conexion();
                                    $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT PaisNom FROM paises WHERE PaisCod = :valor LIMIT 1;");
                                    $stmt->bindParam(':valor', $pais);
                                    $stmt->execute();

                                    $registro = $stmt->fetch();

                                    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                                        echo $registro["PaisNom"];
                                    } else {
                                        echo $pais;
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </td>

                            <td class="center aligned">
                                <a href="ver_instalador.php?var=<?php echo base64_encode($row['idusuario']);?>" class="ui green icon button"><i class="eye icon"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php }} ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Qué puede ser que esté ocurriendo que me los muestra en mysql y no en la página ?

Comment: Hola, has probado de esta forma`T3.nrologins` en vez de `nrologins` o agragando un alias en la consulta `T3.nrologins AS nrologins` por ejemplo.

Comment: creo que es lo mismo, porque la razon social en la consulta esta como T1.razonsocial y lo toma bien... lo que noté es que si pongo la provincia y país despues de la columna de servicios no me muestra esos valores, pero probe poner esas dos columnas por delante de los servicios y salen bien !!! es EXTRAÑISIMO !!!

Comment: ¿Te has dado cuenta de que **ocultas dos celdas de tu tabla con `<td hidden>`**? Aquí en los `th`: **`<th hidden>nrologins</th>
                        <th hidden>Id</th>`** y en las filas dinámicas: **`<td hidden>
                                <?php echo $row['nrologins']; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td hidden>
                                <?php echo $row['idusuario']; ?>
                            </td>`** ¿Las haces visibles luego por CSS o no? Luego, cuando funcione eso, ciertamente tu código es mejorable en algunos aspectos...

Comment: @A.Cedano si si, esas celdas las oculto pero esas celdas me recuperan valores, probe "mostrándolas" y andan perfecto... no entiendo por que poniendo las columnas provincia y pais despues de la columna servicios no me muestra datos...

Comment: Precisamente, una de las malas prácticas que tiene tu código es crear una nueva instancia de `$conexion` dentro de ese bucle: `$conexion = new Conexion();` y además lo haces varias veces, en provincias y en pais. Ya tienes una instancia `$conexion` que has creado al principio del todo y debe estar activa... no hay necesidad de crear otra. No estoy seguro si eso puede afectar a tus resultados finales... pero desde el punto de vista del rendimiento es una mala práctica. Sería interesante que revises tu archivo `error_log` el cual sin duda te dirá lo que está ocurriendo.

Comment: Supongamos que tu SELECT inicial arroja 50 filas,  o 100 filas, o 1,840 filas. **¡Estarías conectando a la BD esa cantidad de veces multiplicado por dos!**. Es muy probable que en tu `error_log` tengas errores de este tipo: `User tu-usuario already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections` o algo parecido.

Comment: @A.Cedano ah ok... es decir que si existe $conexion = new Conexion(); una sola vez, alcanza en la página que tiene el foco...

Comment: Correcto. Dado que está declarada al principio la conexión se puede usar en cualquier parte del script.